# Помогите с сортировкой данных из массива

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, chrome-extension

я пишу расширение задача такая брать инфу со страницы и посылать её в гугл таблицы с помощью апи,с апи проблем нету уже написала код для запроса но вот с инфой проблемы все нужным мне данные находятся в таблице

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  let tableData = [];

 $('#referred_affiliates tbody tr td').each(function(index, element){
  tableData.push($(element).text());
 });

 console.log(tableData);
});
```

с помощью джейквери я ложу все данные в массив но в чём проблема мне нужно данные отсортировать

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

как видно из скрина мне нудно чтоб 0 элемент 4 , 8 ,12 и тд помешались в подкатегорию или в другой массив с названием Name

1 , 5 ,9 и тд помешались в под категорию или в другой массив с названием mail

2 , 6 ,10 и тд помешались в под категорию или в другой массив с названием purchases

3 , 7 ,11 и тд помешались в под категорию или в другой массив с названием create

как кто напрямую получать разные данные для массивов нельзя поскольку они все в одинаковых Td тегах

помогите пожалуйста наперёд спасибо

Answer (score 2):

Думаю лучше всего будет что то типа:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    let tableData = [];

    $('#referred_affiliates tbody tr').each(function (index, tr) {
        let row = [];
        tr.('td').each(function (rowId, rowData) {
            row[rowId] = rowData
        });

        tableData.push(row)
    })

    console.log(tableData);
});
```

а далее воспользоваться пользовательской сортировкой

https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: сортировка кажется уже не нужна будет

Comment: почему то код не работает пишет ошибка в 6 строке Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (

Answer (score 0):

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

  let tableData = {
    created: [],
    purchases: [],
    email: [],
    name: []

  };

  $('#referred_affiliates tbody tr').each(function(index, element) {
    if (index != 0) {
      tableData.name.push($(element).children().eq(0).text());
      tableData.email.push($(element).children().eq(1).text());
      tableData.purchases.push($(element).children().eq(2).text());
      tableData.created.push($(element).children().eq(3).text());
    }

  });

  console.log(tableData);
});
```

мне ответы не помогли вот как я решила если кому то нужно

Comment: Зачем же Вы галочку тогда поставили?) Так Вы введёте в заблуждение будущих пользователей с аналогичной проблемой

Comment: все убрала галочку)